# Meteor roles: Can't mix grouped and non-grouped roles

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm trying to update roles for users, but everytime I want to give/remove the admin role (a global role) it tells me I can't mix them. I dont know how to solve this issue.

```
Meteor.users.update(id, {
    $set: {
        'username': username,
        'emails.0.address': email
    }
});

if(Roles.userIsInRole(id, ['mod'])) {
    Roles.removeUsersFromRoles(id, 'mod');
}

if(Roles.userIsInRole(id, ['admin'])) {
    Roles.removeUsersFromRoles(id, 'admin');
}

if(role == 'Moderator') {
    Roles.addUsersToRoles(id, 'mod');
} else if(role == 'Administrator') {
    Roles.addUsersToRoles(id, 'admin');
}
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: did my answer solve your issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### tl;dr

You must assign roles to the global group like so:

```
Roles.addUsersToRoles(id, 'admin', Roles.GLOBAL_GROUP);
```

---

### Detail:

That error occurs when a user has been assigned roles with a group and without a group. As the docs say:

> NOTE: If you use groups for ANY of your users, you should use groups for ALL of your users. This is due to how the roles package stores the roles internally in the database.

Specifically (from the docs):

```
Roles.addUsersToRoles(bobsUserId, ['manage-team','schedule-game'])
// internal representation - no groups
// user.roles = ['manage-team','schedule-game']

Roles.addUsersToRoles(joesUserId, ['manage-team','schedule-game'], 'manchester-united.com')
Roles.addUsersToRoles(joesUserId, ['player','goalie'], 'real-madrid.com')
// internal representation - groups
// NOTE: MongoDB uses periods to represent hierarchy so periods in group names
//   are converted to underscores.
//
// user.roles = {
//   'manchester-united_com': ['manage-team','schedule-game'],
//   'real-madrid_com': ['player','goalie']
// }
```

Assigning a group to a user, converts the roles property from an array to an object, future changes then must specify a group.

To assign global roles you must specify the global group like so:

```
Roles.addUsersToRoles(id, 'admin', Roles.GLOBAL_GROUP);
```